# Point to the file in bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have following command line runs on windows cmd which runs some custom binary with options:

```
DataReader.exe -s test -t "tag:=code1 OR tag:=code2" --estimatedTagscount 40 --enableWrite --outFileName "C:\temp\data_test" –printTags
```

since I have a lot of tags - code1, code2 and etc., up to 500 and don't want to put all in cmd line, how I can create bat file and instead of having all codes point to file contains all the codes?

thanks,
S

Comment: Does the `DataReader.exe` program support using a file of  tags? That would be the easiest way. It is less easy to write a batch file to construct the command by reading a file, but it can be done. Keep in mind that the command line limit is 8191 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PowerShell script that might do it. I do not have your DataReader.exe and cannot test it.

Create a `codes.txt` file with each code on a line.

```
code1
code2
code3
```

Then create the script file `joincodes.ps1`.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()
$codes = Get-Content .\codes.txt
$line = 'tag:= ' + ($codes -join ' OR tag:=')
Write-Verbose $line

$args = '-s test -t "' + $line + '" --estimatedTagscount 40 --enableWrite --outFileName "C:\temp\data_test" --printTags'
Write-Verbose $args

& "DataReader.exe" $args
```

If you need to run it from a cmd.exe prompt, put the code above into a file such as `joincodes.ps1`, then run it with:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\joincodes.ps1
```

To see the verbose debugging output, use:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\joincodes.ps1 -Verbose
```

Comment: Hi, thanks all!! the one with powershell looks better since the tag can have different name.

Comment: If this works for you, then https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, 100) do DataReader.exe -s test -t "tag:=code%x ...
```

Comment: Or if you need everything in one line, let is echo the options and %x